# Removing harmful gases from automobile exhaust using electrostatic precipitation

Tags: physical-chemistry, purification, adsorption, absorption

If I attach an electrostatic precipitator to a car's exhaust - and also make the smoke pass through an area containing $\ce{NaOH}$ in order to absorb sulfur dioxide - does that mean that the smoke that emerges will not contain harmful gasses such as $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{SO2}$? If not, what is the reason?